# how can i do a matrix with left subscript

Tags: matrices

How do i add both subscripts and superscripts to a matrix? i need 3 indexes, like in the picture.
[image: matrix_example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regular commands `_` and `^` for right subscript and superscript respectively, and use the `\prescript` command from `mathtools` for the left subscript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathbf{A} = \prescript{}{a}{\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    a_{m1} & a_{m2} & \cdots & a_{mn}
\end{bmatrix}_b^c}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it worked well for me. thank you.